# Fit curve not working?

Tags: bezier-curves

So I have these two object and I want them to loop around this NurbsCircle, The curve modifier is working but it seems the array modifier isn't doing its job to "fit curve", Am I doing something wrong?[image]

Comment: did you apply scale for both? if yes, and still not working, please provide blend file

Comment: Ah, thank you, that fixed it.